# SQLite3 querying a database with '?' placeholders

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table named shoes with `names` and `prices`.

This code works and queries two rows:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE name LIKE '%nike tiempo%' AND sizes LIKE '%11.5%' ORDER BY price")

c.fetchall()

[('http://www.final-score.com/product/model:252604/sku:19215108/nike-tiempo-genio-ii-leather-ic-mens/white/orange/', "Nike Tiempo Genio II Leather IC - Men's", 31.99, '06.0, 11.5, 12.0', ''), ('http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/tiempo-legend-vi-mens-firm-ground-soccer-cleat/pid-11155502/pgid-11917874', 'Nike Tiempo Legend VI FG', 169.97, 'M 6 / W 7.5, M 6.5 / W 8, M 7 / W 8.5, M 7.5 / W 9, M 8 / W 9.5, M 8.5 / W 10, M 9 / W 10.5, M 9.5 / W 11, M 10 / W 11.5, M 10.5 / W 12, M 11 / W 12.5, M 11.5 / W 13, M 12 / W 13.5, M 12.5 / W 14, M 13 / W 14.5, M 14 / W 15.5', "Men's Firm-Ground Soccer Cleat")]
```

But when I do the same thing but using '?' placeholders:

```
>>> c.execute("SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE name LIKE '%?%' AND sizes LIKE '%?%' ORDER BY price", ('nike tiempo','11.5'))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 2 supplied.
```

Anyone know what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure about SQLite, but usually those "placeholders" are called parameters and you suppose to use them differently:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE name LIKE ? AND sizes LIKE ? ORDER BY price", ('%nike tiempo%','%11.5%'))
```

Values provided in parameters are not injected into sql string using replace method - otherwise you could just use... string replace. The point is values are formatted and prepared accordingly based on target data type.

What is the most important about this method is that values are also appropriately escaped. What does it mean? It means no one is going to break your SQL string by injecting escape characters and running his own sql statement - hence name for this: [SQL Injection](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_injection.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did the trick. Yeah I tried to avoid just using simple replace methods for those possible sql injections.